# Axiomatization of distributions Poisson and beyond

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, book-recommendation

The Poisson distribution has a well-known axiomatization:

```
Events are occurring independently.
The average rate (number of occurrences in a unit period) is constant.
Two events cannot occur at exactly the same instant.
The probability of more than one occurrence in a sufficiently small period is negligible.
```

My question is, what is the relevant literature,i.e. a good book, that concretely axiomatizes dozens of known p.d.f. each by several different set of axioms at best ?

Comment: I don’t see how that’s an axiomatic statement of the Poisson distribution. I’d like to learn more.

Comment: @Aruralreader It is not the shortest proof in mathematics I know of, but I've seen it in some lecture. But I'm even more curious about the others p.d.f.s.

Comment: [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) $\ne$ [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut OK. What about the others distributions: can uniform distribution be also considered as a process, or not ? How do they briefly differ: oisson distribution and Poisson process ? Your links are too long. What other processes can be axiomatized ?

Comment: The normal distribution has many interesting characterizations, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/what-is-the-most-surprising-characterization-of-the-gaussian-normal-distributi).